# Función para traer datos con selección de estado

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Para recuperar datos de un json y mostrarlo en una tabla donde la selección se hace a través de un button que tiene múltiples opciones como {ítems:["Pendientes", "Resueltos", "Aprobado", "Todos"]}, y se muestra la tabla con un modal/toggle

te mando lo que tengo en código, lo que no me estaría dando cuenta es como hacer la lógica para que el botón me traiga los resultados que elijo dependiendo del estado/ítems

archivo cliente.js

```
<div>
    <div style={{marginLeft:'10.333%'}}>
        <Form id="fieldEstado" formData={this.props.handleBuscarEstado} onFieldDataChanged={this.formFieldDataChanged} >
            <GroupItem cssClass="first-group" colCount={3}>
                <GroupItem colSpan={1}>  
                    <SimpleItem
                        dataField="estado"
                        editorType="dxSelectBox"
                        editorOptions={
                        {items:["Pendientes", "Resueltos", "Aprobado", "Todos"]}
                        }
                    />
                </GroupItem>
                <GroupItem colSpan={2}  >
                    <div className="sm-3 text-center mb-2"  style={buscarEstadosBtn}>
                        <button type="button"className="btn btn-dark"  onClick={this.handleBuscarEstado} >
                            <span className="iconify mr-2" data-icon="bx:bx-search-alt" data-inline="false" data-width="20px" ></span>
                            <b>Consultar Estado</b>
                        </button>
                    </div> 
                </GroupItem>
            </GroupItem>
        </Form>
    </div>                    
</div>
<div>
    {
    <Animated animationIn="fadeIn" className="w-95 mx-auto mt-2">
        <ListaEstados datosPersonales={this.state.datosPersonales} getIdCliente={this.getIdCliente} getKeyLogin={this.props.getKeyLogin} />
    </Animated>
    }
</div>
```

archivo listaEstados.js

```
class ListaEstados extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {    
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    render() {
        const datos = process.env.REACT_APP_WS_ACTU_DATOS;
        return(
            <>
                <div className="wrap">
                    <h2 className="centrar">{this.state.titulo}</h2>
                    <div className="bg-light p-3 border cont-table" style={{ maxHeight: 
                        $("#panelResultados").height() - 45 }}>
                        <div className="cont-table">
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Nombre </th>
                                        <th>Apellido </th>
                                        <th>Estado Registración </th>
                                        <th>Correo </th>
                                        <th>Telefono </th> 
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {
                                    [datos].map((datosPersonales)=>(
                                        <tr key={datosPersonales.cliente}  >
                                        <th>{datosPersonales.nombre} </th>
                                        <th>{datosPersonales.apellido} </th>
                                        <th>{datosPersonales.estadoRegistro} </th>
                                        <th>{datosPersonales.email} </th>
                                        <th>{datosPersonales.nroTelefono} </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    ))
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }  
}
```

la idea es que me traiga del json solo los estados q le voy a solicitar…

Bueno no se si esta claro… si no, por favor avisame. Hace varios dias estoy bloqueada con esto y más vuelta le doy menos veo la salida… se q no es gran cosa quizás, pero para mi me es un dolor de cabeza :(

Desde ya gracias a cualquier aporte!

Comment: Primero, no incluyas el código como imágenes, no es bien visto por la comunidad, puedes incluir el código directamente en tu pregunta. Y segundo, procura tener un código mínimo verificable: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Porque tienes

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, me ayuda a progresar!

Comment: Puedes ahora ayudarme a mí a despejar dudas y avanzar en el aprendizaje?

Comment: Desde ya gracias!♣